# Include Description in Uploaded File

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm using Graph API, using example code in [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) I'm able to upload file to `OneDrive`.

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var stream = "The contents of the file goes here."

await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["{item-id}"]
    .Request()
    .PutAsync(stream);
```

Question is, I want to include `Description` to the uploaded file.
I don't know if this possible, but couldn't find info on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether `OneDrive personal` or `OneDrive for Business`/`SharePoint document library` [drive type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/drive?view=graph-rest-1.0) is utilized.

From [`driveItem` resource type page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

> `description` `String` Provides a user-visible description of the item. Read-write. **Only on OneDrive Personal**

In case of OneDrive Personal, `driveItem.Description` property could be updated like this:

```
//upload a file
var driveItem = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[itemId]
    .Content
    .Request()
    .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);


//update driveItem
var updateItem = new DriveItem { Description = "File uploaded" };
await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[driveItem.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(updateItem);
```

Comment: Hi, while your code work it will create at least 2 *request*..
If I have to upload  20+ item with description, the code will make 40 *request*

Comment: @AskTooMuch, regarding optimizing the requests what you are after is called [JSON batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching). MS Graph C# SDK also supports it, [refer here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-design/blob/master/content/BatchRequestContent.md) for a details